# What if I want to work on a different bug after another patch being accepted

Tags: git, github

I just started to use Github, and practiced it locally on my PC. I then found a Github project and start fixing its bugs.

1. I forked the project and downloaded it to my PC
2. I opened a branch. Start fixing on that branch.
3. I pushed the patch branch back to Github
4. Switch to that branch on Github and sent the pull request to developer.
5. The patch was accepted.

But now I want to work on a second bug. How do I update my fork at Github and my local copy to the newest official version(with my patch and a few other new patches by others)?

Do I need to close both my patch-branch at my local and on Github? And do I close them individually?

Or would I just delete my fork and refork a new one again?

Answer (score 2):

Assume your fork is located at `git://github.com/lulalala/foo.git` and the upstream repo is at `git://github.com/someuser/foo.git`.

First you need to add their repository as a remote.

```
git remote add upstream git://github.com/someuser/foo.git
```

Now that you have added their repository you can fetch their branches.

```
git fetch upstream
git branch -a # Look, you've got their branches!*
```

Checkout their master branch and then rebase it on to yours.

```
git checkout upstream/master
git rebase master
```

Now push back to your fork on GitHub

```
git push origin master
```

Voila!

```
* You don't actually have their branches, you need to check them out to have a physical copy.
```

Comment: Thanks! When I checkout upstream/master, I get the message "You are in 'detached HEAD' state." and I am then in the "(no branch)". Is this expected?

Comment: After the rebase I am in the '(no branch)'. And pushing it would generate the message 'Everything up-to-date'. And my Github fork still has not changed.

Comment: You will need to checkout back to your master branch, `git checkout master` after rebasing.

Comment: Yes I tried that but it didn't work either. However this does work http://bradlyfeeley.com/2008/09/03/update-a-github-fork-from-the-original-repo/

Comment: I guess I found the issue. Instead of `git rebase master` I did `git checkout master` `git rebase upstream/master` to apply current master on top of upstream/master. What do you think? If you think it is correct and edited the answer I'll accept it :D